# 3 prong unneeded range outlet... adapter for 2 prong toaster?

Tags: range, cord-and-plug

I have a 3 prong range outlet that I don't need anymore.  Is there a simple plug adapter so I can run toaster 3 prong 110v etc?

Comment: That sounds like a problem, what size is the breaker, what size is the wire, and what size is the cord on the toaster?

Comment: You might not need the outlet for the range any more, but the next resident might. There are weird people who prefer to cook with electricity rather than gas.

Comment: @FreeMan   I cook with gas, but it seems like there is a lot of wasted heat.  My next range is going to have an induction cooktop.  I've cooked  at my church for large groups and we have 4 3,500 watt induction burners, they are awesome.  Very efficient, very little lost heat.

Comment: Can't do it, the 3-wire range connection does not have a GROUND.  Possible the cable in the wall could be re-tasked, but this is not a "plug-in deal". It needs to be re-wired at both ends, and breaker changed to 20A.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR No.

There are at least four possible problems here:

- Breaker Size

The breaker is probably between 30A and 50A. When you start plugging in items designed for a 15A or 20A circuit, that doesn't work. There are some adapters that can handle this properly by including a circuit breaker or fuse so that the circuit is being extended with a 15A or 20A limit. But your typical cheap adapter won't have that (and may have other safety issues as well).

This problem can be solved, but normally on a more permanent basis, by replacing the breaker with a 20A breaker and replacing the receptacle (since you can't have a 30A receptacle on a 20A circuit).

- GFCI

A kitchen small appliance circuit normally requires GFCI. You might be able to get away without that if it is more than 6 feet from the sink. A typical little adapter won't include GFCI protection.

- 3-Prong Receptacle

3-prong stove receptacle indicates a long-obsolete receptacle that does not have separate neutral and ground. Depending on how things are currently wired, you may have an available ground wire that is simply not in use, such that you could replace with a modern 4-prong receptacle, or replace with a 120V grounded circuit (which is 3 prongs, but different from the 3 you have now). If you don't have an available ground then you are really stuck here as the simple fixes just won't (legally and safely) work.

- Required Circuit

Depending on local code, other appliances/circuits (e.g., gas stove, electric oven), you *may* be required to have this stove circuit even if you don't actually want to use it yourself.

So what would be reasonably legal and safe?

- Check ground and retrofit if needed

To do just about anything, you need a proper ground. A 3-wire stove receptacle will *usually* have two hots and neutral but no ground. If it is metal conduit then that should provide a proper ground. If it has a ground wire that just wasn't connected, that will provide a proper ground. Or you can retrofit ground by running just a ground wire (size depends on your circuit size, which is determined by the breaker) either back to the panel or, possibly, to a ground wire in another circuit.

Once you have a good ground, you have 3 choices:

- Subpanel

The more expensive, but more flexible, option is a subpanel. You can then use the 30A (or 40A or 50A, depends on wire size) available and connect multiple circuits. But it could be a lot of work and it requires open space in front of the subpanel, which in a typical kitchen you just won't have.

- Multi-Wire Branch Circuit

This makes use of *both* hots. It requires a 20A double-breaker (or two single-breakers handle-tied, but double-breaker is easier). Due to the way GFCI works, highly recommended to use a GFCI/breaker to keep things relatively simple. This will actually give you effectively 2 x 20A circuits, so you can split it to multiple receptacles and handle toaster and coffee maker at the same time. You can install a split duplex receptacle or two separate duplex receptacles or a number of other possibilities.

- Regular Circuit

This makes use of only one hot (plus neutral and ground, of course). Replace the existing double-breaker with a single 20A breaker. You can use the now-empty space for a different circuit. Cap the unused hot on both ends. Install a GFCI/receptacle to replace the existing receptacle.

Answer (score 0):

There might be, but product recommendations are OT here.  But besides that, it's a really bad idea to simply use an adapter, you'll have **woefully inadequate over-current protection**. Your range outlet is probably 40 or 50 amps at 240v. That's "a bit much" (sarcasm intended) for a 120v appliance.  Not only that, your 3 prong outlet is probably 2 hots and a ground, no neutral, no way to connect a 120v outlet. All you could do is re-wire the feed to the range outlet in the panel with a new   breaker at 20 amps, move one of the hots (which you'll need to mark with white tape) to the neutral bus bar and swap out the range outlet for a standard 120v outlet. Because you'll be working with 8 ga or 6 ga wire, you'll need special wire nuts to connect to pig tails to connect to the new outlet.  EDIT:  If you go this route, which I don't recommend, you'll need to attach a label to the repurposed range wires indicating there is 12ga or 14ga wires as part of the circuit.

OK.  that said, I want to be clear:  This is **NOT A RECOMMENDATION**  I think it's code legal, but not sure.  There are other more hacky ways of doing it, but I'm not going to say what they are. I would encourage you not to do this.

Comment: Not only would the toaster not be properly protected from an over current, but you wouldn't be able to fit the #6 or #8 wires from the range wiring into a standard 15 or 20A wall receptacle. For a reason!

Comment: @FreeMan yeah, that's why I mentioned pig-tails.   Also I forgot to mention that the wires in the panel need to be labeled saying there is 12 ga as part of the circuit, I'll add that.

Comment: Not sure if a non-white wire can be marked white for neutral as a white wire can be marked for hot for the smaller gauges(large feeders can be).

Comment: @crip659  You could be right, at best it'd be skirting the edges of the code, but at least it'd be marked, even if not fully code legal.   Again, I still think it's an ill conceived idea.  Also, I wonder why he wants to do this? Is there inadequate power in his kitchen?

Comment: Thanks, Guys!  Perfectly explained!  I don't want the range and have that space for toaster, etc.  Only electric on that wall is refrigerator and range.

Comment: @TomClark _you_ may not want the range, but future owners might. Also, code might _require_ an outlet for the range whether you use it or not. All in all, it sounds like this is a bad idea from a DIY perspective.